# Why koa-router sends 404?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

I'm using a koa-router, koa-views and sequelize. Data comes from a database, but the status = 404. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.get('/', function *() {
  var ctx = this;

  yield models.drivers.findAll({
    where: {
      userId: ctx.passport.user.id
    }
  }).then(function(drivers) {
    ctx.render('driversSearch', {
      drivers: drivers
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not taking advantage of Koa's coroutine features. Your code can be rewritten like this:

```js
router.get('/', function *() {
  var drivers = yield models.drivers.findAll({
    where: {
      userId: this.passport.user.id
    }
  });

  this.render('driversSearch', {
    drivers: drivers
  });
});
```

Koa uses [the co library](https://github.com/tj/co) under the hood. If you yield a promise, the generator function will pause and then resume when the promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Works if: yield this.render(). Thanks!